# How do I find out the tag of a view I am touching

Tags: iphone, uiview

I am having trouble determining the tag of the view I am touching.

I have a scroll view and subclassed it in order to capture touch down events (I have pictures on the subview). However, I need to determine which picture I touched down.

I want to determine that tag of the subview, but I am getting random results (mostly tag 0). Whats the proper way of capturing this?

Comment: You can tag subviews like view.tag = 99

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `UIView hitTest`. It will return you the subview the user is touching.